# How to get started development inside docker container in windows operating system

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-10, workflow, wsl-2

I am a developer who is using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS regularly for my development. I never install any packages like, node, PHP, python in the OS and make use of docker for the purpose. VS Code is the editor I use, and the extension of the remote container will help me to develop & debug inside the docker container.

Right now, I am in the process of moving the development to a windows environment and I wanted to follow a similar workflow there too. Unfortunately, I am facing few issues like "file changes are not getting detected" (when npm serve in angular and react projects).
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739
https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/c48yej/wsl_2_react_not_reloading_with_file_changes/

I have tried different methods to solve the issue like

- use `wsl2` and then `docker` inside that and then serve from the container
- use just `docker` and serve the code from inside the container

Regardless of the methods, the file changes are not getting detected inside the docker.
Trust me I have gone through many bizarre words like `inotify`, increasing the watchers, etc... Nothing helped.
Is there a developer out there following a similar practice in a Windows environment? (docker + windows)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I use nodemon for nodejs rest api's and it works under the Linux fs but not under the windows fs. So, when using wsl2 with VSC, ensure that you're using the Linux filesystem, not the windows filesystem.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer: How about remote containers? Are you developing inside the docker container? That is my primary objective.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving the files to the wsl2 file system and not the windows.

Wsl2 'sees' the windows file system from inside a mount image /mnt/c .
Move out of it, like at ~ (cd ~) and i think your files will be normally watched .

Comment: Agreed, but the solution I am looking for is with the docker container. Even though we move our project to wsl2 file system, we would have to install node in wsl2. I don't want that. Instead, I want to make use of the vscode feature of developing inside a container. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: I usually go inside a wsl2 filesystem ( like cd ~/project ) and press:  `code .` . Then visual studio code opens inside the folder of the wsl2. It may be a problem if you use other tools for developing like github desktop etc. But at least visual studio code can work on files of wsl2.